Must fact tables be designed for aggregation?
I have been reading up on Microsoft SQL Server's columnstore indexes recently and I have become concerned that my experience does not match that of the industry. Columnstore indexes are designed to make aggregates easy. It is very frequently said that for this reason they are an ideal fit for fact tables.
This make me uneasy. In my experience, fact tables are not aggregated. The column list for every fact table I have ever made has been of the form "primary key followed by several dimension columns, followed by every bit of info we store about the primary key". They then get dumped into some BI tool like PowerBI or ThoughtSpot, so non-technical people can filter based on the dimensions and find out whatever they want to know. They might aggregate from time to time, but this certainly isn't the main use of the table. I expect such tables to have well over 100 columns.
Is the table design and access pattern I am describing what is expected of a fact table? Or am I describing an entirely different type of table, the name of which I am ignorant?


The column list for every fact table I have ever made has been of the form "primary key followed by several dimension columns, followed by every bit of info we store about the primary key"...Is the table design and access pattern I am describing what is expected of a fact table?

No, this is just a denormalized table.
Fact tables and Dimension tables are meant to be separate in a properly modeled data warehouse that follows classic Star schema design pattern. Dimension tables are usually a unique list of descriptive information relating to your data objects (particularly the measures of your fact tables) aka qualitative data. Fact tables are the quantitative data aka the measures themselves, which are typically numerical data for analytical purposes.
Usually facts are stored disaggregated (to a reasonable degree) so that it can be aggregated to different degrees for different combinations of dimensions. Pre-aggregating the facts makes it not possible to run analytical queries and answer questions at lower level granularities.  Here's some more details and an example.
I'm not sure how your current design handles multiple dimension combinations, perhaps you have repeated rows for the same dimension with each of its combinations for other dimensions in the same table?

Columnstore indexes are designed to make aggregates easy. It is very frequently said that for this reason they are an ideal fit for fact tables.

Yes, this is true for the most part. They help make aggregations and analytical queries perform better by compressing data at a columnar level, and perhaps even more importantly, through being able to utilize batch mode operations to serve those queries.

I'm confused. You've said that pre-aggregation is not good in fact tables, but the example you've linked to has AVG_SALES in its fact table. Aren't averages aggregates?

@J.Mini "Usually facts are stored disaggregated (to a reasonable degree)". In the linked example they mostly store the data disaggregated to the lowest granularity. The AVG_SALES column isn't an aggregate over the rows, likely they mean the result of the formula AMT_SOLD / QTY_SOLD within the same row, to get the average sale price per unit (column name could've been better). Note I never said pre-aggregating is a bad thing, it just limits you to being unable to answer questions at lower granularities. So one could make a case for pre-aggregating some measures to some degrees.
